# How to monitor and auto-restart geth with monit?

Tags: go-ethereum, ubuntu, monitoring

**I want [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) to restart geth on crashes and send me alerts by email.**

Here is what I'm trying to do.

My monit config at **/etc/monit/conf.d/geth.cfg**

```
# GETH
CHECK PROCESS geth with pidfile "/home/username/monit/geth.pid"
    start program = "/bin/bash -c '/home/username/monit/geth.sh start'" as uid username as gid username
    stop program = "/bin/bash -c '/home/username/monit/geth.sh stop'" as uid username as gid username
    if not exist then alert
    if not exist then restart
```

And the start/stop script **/home/username/monit/geth.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
PID='/home/username/monit/geth.pid'
LOGS='/home/username/monit/geth.log'
KEYS='\--fast --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain localhost --ipcpath /home/username/.ethereum/geth.ipc --cache=16'

case $1 in
   start)
       setsid geth "$KEYS" &> "$LOGS" & 
       echo $! > "$PID"
   ;;
   stop)
      cat "$PID"
      kill -SIGINT `cat "$PID"`
      rm "$PID"
   ;;
   *)
      echo "usage: geth.sh {start|stop}" ;;
esac
exit 0
```

I can run geth with *sudo monit start geth*, but monit cannot see geth's pid right. So it will not restart geth on crashes. The problems in my script:

1. Cannot define geth's pid right. The geth.pid receives a process number which is higher by 2-4 numbers (e.g. 4678 instead of 4674).
2. Cannot kill geth with -SIGINT, have to send -HUP signal instead.

I understand this is more like a Linux question, then Ethereum's, but I believe it may be very useful.

The closest howto's I found on geth monitoring are:

- [Restart Geth from another process](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/restart-geth-from-another-process)
- [Setting up geth Ethereum node to run automatically on Ubuntu](https://hiddentao.com/archives/2016/05/04/setting-up-geth-ethereum-node-to-run-automatically-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: "$KEYS" shouldn't be in quotes in the start) clause.  Works for me after removing those.

Answer (score 2):

I did find a temporary working solution. It restarts geth just fine and sends alerts. But if you want to stop geth here you'll have to unmonitor it first with *sudo monit unmonitor geth* and then gracefully kill it with -SIGINT signal manually. Otherwise it gets killed with -HUP.

Monit config. /etc/monit/conf.d/geth.cfg

```
# GETH
CHECK PROCESS geth MATCHING "[g]eth.*fast"
    start program = "/bin/bash -c 'geth --fast --rpc --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain localhost --cache=16 >/dev/null 2> /home/my-logs-folder/geth.log'" as uid username as gid username
    stop program = "/bin/bash -c 'kill -HUP $(ps aux | grep '[g]eth' | awk '{print $2}')'" as uid username as gid username
    if not exist then alert
    if not exist then restart
```

I believe the better approach is the script cited in the question, so I'm not marking this as the answer.